# How to copy an existing maven repository contents from one machine to other?

Tags: maven-3, nexus

I am supposed to put up the Nexus Repository Manager for an existing Maven Repository. However the maven repo is currently in production, which I will not be able to work on. So I am planning to take an exact replica of the maven repo into a sandbox and start working on the it.

Will just copying the folder contents work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just copying will work.  We use `rsync` to do this and have no problems.  If you are using Windows, you can also setup cygwin to do this if you want to copy every so often.

At the least you can just zip it up, copy it, and unzip it on the target machine.